# ¿Por qué get() y size() no han sido implementados?

Tags: java, clase-abstracta

Tengo una función panel1 que devuelve un iterador que funciona con el siguiente programa:

```
public class Panel{

    public static Iterable<Integer> panel1(final int begin,final int end){
        return new Iterable<Integer>() {
            public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
                Iterator<Integer> it = new Iterator<Integer>(){

                    private int nextValue = begin;
                    private final int max = end;

                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return nextValue <= max;
                    }

                    public Integer next() {
                        if (!hasNext()) {
                            throw new NoSuchElementException();
                        }
                        return Integer.valueOf(nextValue++);
                    }

                    public void remove() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }
                };
                return it;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         for (int i : panel1(1,5)) {
            System.out.println(i);
         }
    }
}
```

Quiero hacer que el Panel se vea como cualquier objeto de Lista. He visto la documentación de AbstractList y parece hacer el trabajo. Me preguntaba qué problemas estaba respondiendo esta clase. Parece que `AbstractList` se utiliza para implementar una lista no modificable, para la cual simplemente necesito extender la clase de `AbstractList` e implementar solo los métodos `get()` y `size()`.

¿Por qué estos métodos no han sido implementados?

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta más simple es *porque AbstractList es abstracta y no necesita implementar todos los métodos*.

Ahondando un poco. AbstractList tampoco tiene alguna implementación coherente de los métodos *add*. Y no tienen ningún objeto interno donde guardar los datos. Por lo tanto no sabe cómo se debe implementar *get* - no sabe de dónde sacar el objeto que se pide, y tampoco *size* - no hay nada a lo que le podamos medir el tamaño.

Mira [esto](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java).

Las implementaciones de AbstractList, al no ser abstractas, ya tendrán sus métodos *get* y *size*.

Espero haberte ayudado.